# Free Android app to track quitting bad habits

Tags: gratis, android, health

I am looking for an Android app or a way to track quitting bad habits.

There are many such apps on Google Play, but it seems that most of them are time-based, e.g., tracking hours or days of being sober. I am looking for something which is count activity based, so more like tracking the number of drinks per day.

Alcohol is just an example. I am looking for a generic app that can be used for any kind of bad habit. Also, it does not have to be an app dedicated specifically to quitting bad habits. Any app that allows maintaining a count for different values per day and seeing statistics would do.

### Features

1. I want to see progress statistics such as the highest streak and the current streak for each count.
2. I want to be able to save the data on the cloud or be able to export and import it to another device.
3. The app should open quickly in order to be able to open it, increment a counter (e.g., drinks per day), and close it in a matter of seconds.

### Why not use a spreadsheet?

I could use a spreadsheet for this, but it would be more time-consuming to find and open the particular spreadsheet. Also, text tends to be too small on phones when using Google Sheets or similar software.

I could also use a simple note-taking app, but I would not be able to see statistics.

### Example

The best app I was able to find is [Timecap](https://timecap.app/). However, it has a few flaws. E.g., it does not show the streak for each habit but only the highest current and all-time streak among all of them. Also, the free version does not have statistics or cloud saving.

Comment: Not using any such myself, but maybe have a look at: [Habits](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.dwett.habits) // [To don't](https://f-droid.org/packages/rocks.poopjournal.todont/) // [Loop Habit Tracker](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.isoron.uhabits/)?

Comment: @Izzy "Habits" and "Loop Habit Tracker" seem to be focused on positive habit formation instead of bad habit reduction. "To don't" is way too simple. There is no feature to count the number of times a bad habit is performed, and no statistics.

Comment: "To don't" has statistics, even graphs IIRC (see the 2nd screenshot: DWMY stands for day, week, month, year; unfortunately not much details collected to make that screenshot conclusive). But yes, it's rather kept simple. As I wrote, not using such myself – hence no answer but just a comment in the hope one of them might prove helpful. The other ones I remember are rather too specific (like "stop smoking" with a cigarette counter)…

Comment: @Izzy You are right, it does have some form of statistics but not what I'm looking for. The main issue is that it doesn't have a way to count instances of bad habits, so it wouldn't have statistics related to that count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this tracker before. Habit tracker on the app store, but habit bull once it's installed.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oristats.habitbull

It allows you to do multiple habits and shows aggregate statistics and individual habit statistics as well including streaks, longest, and current, and success percentage. It will show you a collective total as well as averages and a couple fancy graph of your successful days and the values you enter each day.

It will let you see all of your habits, click one and increment or decrement a counter in just a few touches. You can also add yes no habits. Loads fast enough on my device that I consider it a matter of seconds.

There is a sync feature for cloud storage but it might cost something, not sure, I've never tried it.

The only real negative I can think of is that the user interface is a little bit cluttered and not perfectly intuitive in my opinion.

Comment: Just tried it. It seems to have all the features I'm looking for, but the interface, as you said, is not that great.